# r sub negation of [:digit:] in regex

Tags: r, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to use `sub`to remove everything between the end of string `s` (pattern always includes `:`, digits and parentheses ) and up till but not including the first digit before starting parenthis `(`.

```
s <- "NXF1F-Z10_(1:111)"
>sub("\\(1:[[:digit:]]+)$", "", s) #Almost work!
[1] "NXF1F-Z10_"
```

To remove all characters not a digit (like `_` , anything of any length except a digit ) I tried in vain this to negate digits:

```
sub("[^[:digit:]]*(1:[[:digit:]]+)$", "", s)
```

The desired output is :

```
[1] "NXF1F-Z10"
```

Comment: Can't you do something like...
gsub("(.*)$","",s)
and then with a substring method remove that last part?

Comment: What would be the correct output?

Comment: Try a lookbehind. I think this should work for all cases `sub("(?<=\\d)[^\\d]*?\\(\\d*:\\d*\\)$", "", s, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: No need for anything fancy: `sub("\\D*\\(.*$", "", s)` will do it. "\\D" matches non-digit characters, so this deletes all non-digit characters that immediately precede "(" as well as everything that follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s <- "NXF1F-Z10_(1:111)"
```

Try this

```
sub("_.+", "", s)
# "NXF1F-Z10"
```

More general

```
sub("(\\d)[^\\d]*[(].*[)]$", "\\1", s, perl=TRUE)
# "NXF1F-Z10"
sub("(\\d)[^\\d]*[(].*[)]$", "\\1", t, perl=TRUE)
# "NXF1F-Z10"
```

Or this

```
sub("[(](\\d+):.+", "\\1", s)
# "NXF1F-Z10_1"
```

Depending on what you want

Comment: Yes sorry for being unclear in Q. The first gives the desired but cannot be generalized (sometimes `_` can be e.g. `g--H#` ( anything but digit)